# Change Shortcut Icon

Tags: shortcuts, icons

I've googled a lot in case of this issue but couldn't find any post which was helping me. Maybe some of you guys have an idea how to set this up.

In our company we use an order program for our customers which is running on windows and will be installed on the C drive, sometimes on a server on the customers place as well.

We created a new icon for the shortcut on the desktop. On Win10 we only need to put the new exe (new icon) in the installation folder on C. After rebooting the icon is replaced on the desktop shortcut. But if we try to do the same on Win 7 or lower, it doesn't work. There it's only possible after deleting the iconcache and reboot, then the new icon will show up.

Is there a way without deleting iconcache?

Comment: What format the icon that you put has? `.ico` or you link the `.exe` directly? Is the .exe file available in the Windows 7 systems locally available?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not the developer of this program but I gave the developer four different `.ico` files to put into his `.exe`, for the different views in windows. The icon is linked directly to the `.exe` and this is available directly on the local disk C.

Comment: Doing the following: Right click in the shortcut -> Properties -> Shortcut Tab -> Change Icon... -> Select the *new* .exe file should show you the new icons. I can create you a snapshot if you want.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add something: We need to update all programs at the customers place and are not able to change it by hand, so it need to be done automaticly